# Django file upload: filename not sticking

Tags: python, django, file, upload

I'm uploading files and storing metadata in a db.  Part of the metadata is the file name itself.  However, somewhere down the line, the filename seems to not be getting saved!  I will paste only what I think are relevant parts of the code to keep this short.

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
   ...
    theFile = models.FileField(upload_to = "Genius/Uploads/", null = True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True, null = False)

class UploadFileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadFile
        fields = ('title', 'theFile', 'date_uploaded',) # Don't prompt for filename


def files_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.filename = request.FILES['theFile'].name # TODO: sanitize!
            # form.filename = 'foo'
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/files/upload/successful/')
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render_to_response('files/upload_file.html', { 'form': form })
```

I have checked the value of request.FILES['theFile'].name before & after saving the form.  For whatever reason it is intact but never seems to make it into the DB.

Comment: Just a sidenote: Some browsers send you just the filename, others send you the whole path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `form.filename` is the form field, not the value it will be saving.

You are looking for something like this:

```
class UploadFileForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = ModelForm.save(self, commit=False)
        instance.filename = self.files['theFile'].name

        if commit:
            instance.save()

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = UploadFile
        fields = ('title', 'theFile', 'date_uploaded',) # Don't prompt for filename
```

Alternative solution:

```
upload_file = form.save(commit=False)
upload_file.filename = request.FILES['theFile'].name
upload_file.save()
```

Comment: Oh.  So upload_file becomes the instance.. err wait.  I'm confused.  Can you elaborate further?  Noob here.

Comment: @Harv: you're correct. The `form.save()` method returns the instance (and with `commit=True`, it saves it first). There are some other options too ofcourse, you can add the `filename` field to the form and modify the `data` argument to the form. You can modify the `save()` method of the form so it automatically does this inside of the form (you should have `self.files` available in the form).

Comment: Okay, awesome.  Thanks for clearing that up for me.  And for answering so quickly!

Answer (score 1):

Form field values aren't accessed via attributes on the form. So setting 'form.filename' doesn't set the value to be saved in the filename field. Instead, set the value on the instance returned by form.save().

```
upload_file = form.save(commit=False) 
upload_file.filename = filename
upload_file.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that, in the future, you might try to avoid putting such business logic on the model form. While [WoLpH's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840138/django-file-upload-filename-not-sticking/4840277#4840277) answer is correct and a great example of how to handle additional model instance processing through `ModelForm`, particular cases of having fields dependent on other fields data is handled in the `Model`, `Form` and `ModelForm` API through their respected `clean()` methods and is mentioned in several places in the official reference docs (here's one on [forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), though the same holds true for the `Model` and `ModelForm` APIs).

In your case this would mean:

```
import os

class UploadFile(models.Model):

     # ...

     def clean(self):
          # Field data has already been populated by this point.
          # Note that `FieldFile` inherits from `File` and that
          # `File.name` is actually the full path to the file
          # so we need to get the base path component sans the extension

          path, extension = os.path.splitext(self.thefile.file.name)
          self.filename = os.path.basename(path)
```

And that's about it! If you properly set the `editable` attribute on your model fields, you'll find that you can rely on Django to automatically generate the `ModelForm` for the `UploadFile` model. That means you don't have to define a `ModelForm` for the generic create, update views or your model's `ModelAdmin` and that's less lines of code to manage!

The general rule of thumb is that you think twice about whether overriding default behavior is ever justified or self-contained, especially when your working at the far end of the business logic chain, otherwise you may feel the wrath of unexpected flops.